# Dockerfile exists but Docker says it can't locate

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I don't see why docker doesn't build my Dockerfile.  The Dockerfile is present but is complaining it can't locate it.  What am I missing here?  I'm at my wits end right now.

Dockerfile is present, unless my eyes are playing tricks on me.  I think it's spelled correctly too.

```
$ ls
Dockerfile  pct  runme.sh
$
```

Error message I'm getting when running docker build

```
$ cat /tmp/context.tar | docker build -f Dockerfile -t iii - 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  665.6kB
Error response from daemon: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
$
```

Comment: You're trying to `cat` the contents of what appears to be a `tar` file.  Did you mean something like `tar -xf -` instead?

Comment: `-` means that the Dockerfile is in stdin. Try `cat Dockerfile | docker build - -t iii /tmp/context.tar`

Comment: @stdunbar, thx, I was just copying the command I found on another script internally.  I don't know what voodoo the person was doing but it worked for them.  After I played with the docker build command, I think I figured out how to get it working.  I can post what I found as an answer or we can delete my question here if  needed.

Comment: @HansKilian, thx.  After playing with the docker build command and reading your comment, I figured out how to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

So after playing with the ***docker build*** command, I got it working.  I don't know how/why the person catted the tar file and then piped it to docker build but it worked for them but not for me.

The command that worked for me was:

```
$ docker build -f Dockerfile my_dir/ -t image_name
```

Answer (score 0):

> don't know how/why the person catted the tar file and then piped it to docker build

At the end of the day, Docker images are just a collection of tarballs.

Are you sure they were actually using a `Dockerfile`? That's [not a requirement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#usage).

```
cat context.tar | docker build -
```

or , to prevent [UUOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

```
docker build < context.tar
```

[`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) would be better for this.